# Print out the total number of letters - Java

Tags: java

I want to print out the total number of letters (not including whitespace characters) of all the Latin names in the data file. Duplicate letters must be counted. This is what I have done so far:

```
List<Person> peopleFile = new ArrayList<>();
int numberOfLetters = 0;

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("people_data.txt"));
    String fileRead = br.readLine();
    while (fileRead != null) {
        String[] tokenSize = fileRead.split(":");
        String commonName = tokenSize[0];
        String latinName = tokenSize[1];
        Person personObj = new Person(commonName, latinName);
        peopleFile.add(personObj);
        fileRead = br.readLine();
        // Iterating each word
        for (String s: tokenSize) {
            // Updating the numberOfLetters
           numberOfLetters += s.length();
        }
    }
    br.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("file not found");
}
catch (IOException ex) {             
    System.out.println("An error has occured: " + ex.getMessage());
}

System.out.print("Total number of letters in all Latin names = ");
System.out.println(numberOfLetters);
```

The problem is that it prints out all number of letters in the file, I just want it to print out the number of characters in the Latin names.

The text file:

```
David Lee:Cephaloscyllium ventriosum
Max Steel:Galeocerdo cuvier
Jimmy Park:Sphyrna mokarren
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. show sample text from your `people_data.txt` file. And give example what you are expecting from what input.

Comment: I've updated the code.

Comment: add ouput for this same text file

Comment: How would I do that? I just want to print the sum into the console, that's all

Comment: you can certainly count the letters by hand as you know what should be the output from this 2 line of text. Dont you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is **you are counting all the names despite you tokenize them**. You can use this method to count letters of any String or Sentence.

```
public static int countLetter(String name) {
    int count = 0;

    if(name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
        /* This regular expression is splitting String at the
         * sequence of Non-alphabetic characters. Hence actually
         * splitting the Name into group of words */
        String[] tokens = name.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
        for(String token : tokens) {
            count += token.length();
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

And replace these lines

```
        /* Note: here you are iterating all your Names from each line */
        for (String s: tokenSize) {
            // Updating the numberOfLetters
           numberOfLetters += s.length();
        }
```

with this

```
numberOfLetters += countLetter(latinName);
```

Does it make sense ? I hope you found your problem.

**NB:** you can experiment with this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/4RpSrQ/1)

Comment: I've designed a Java class to represent each person, with appropriate instance data, constructors, accessor methods (‘getter’ methods) and an appropriate toString() method. How would this code work?

Comment: There is nothing to do with your `person` object. All your those codes are fine. I just asked to replace the for-loop. Read the answer carefully.

Comment: What I mean is, If I put the first code in the Java class and the last code in the main method, would it work?

Comment: `countLetter(String name)` is a static method, you can put it anywhere you want. Probably you can put it in the class where the `main` method is. And replace the `for-loop` I mentioned from your code with the last line I mentioned. Are you getting this ?

Comment: Yes, I understand but I have to add this code `import static task1.Person.countLetter;` in the main method to make it work. I don't want to use import, is there another way?

Comment: You dont need to import. Why dont you put the method in the class where you are using it ?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the blank spaces before summing the length :

```
  s=s.replaceAll("[ \n\t]+","");
  numberOfLetters += s.length();
```

Comment: I want to print out the number of letters in the latinName array, not the whole text file

Comment: OP is trying to count letters in variable `latinName`, not `commonName` AND `latinName` which is stored in `s` in foreach